# Need help creating a calculated field

Tags: json, data-visualization, tableau-api, xlsx, calculated-field

I currently working with 2 data sets :

- Calls log .XLSX
  Shape:

> Blockquote

| Timestamp | Call centre agent | USER ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/12/2021 17:05:33 | F | 1 |
| 1/12/2021 17:16:15 | F | 1 |
| 1/13/2021 13:15:27 | A | 2 |
| 1/14/2021 13:42:37 | F | 3 |
| 12/30/2020 15:48:27 | B | 4 |

> Blockquote

- Order times .JSON
  Shape:
  {
  "userId": 1020,
  "createdAt": "2020-12-01 20:11:54"
  },
  {
  "userId": 5,
  "createdAt": "2020-12-02 6:42:25"
  },
  {
  "userId": 1005,
  "createdAt": "2020-12-02 6:54:57"
  },

The primary key between both data sets is the user_id, and I loaded both datasets to tableau as two data sources.

What I want to do is to show how many users ordered within chosen number of days after the agent call, the condition is to be if the user ordered within (x) days from the agent call, where x is determined by the user of dashboard.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Join these two dataset by userId key.
2. Make calculated field like this.

   ```sql
   SUM(IF [Timestamp] <= [createdAt] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   ```
3. Put userId on column, calculated field on row.

p.s. this is not tested :)

thanks.